# Is it possible to apply JWT only to my endpoints created in Spring Security 6?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Boot. I would like to handle authentication with JWT exclusively for my endpoints, and for all other requests that do not match my API, I want to use a 404 message. I have this configuration, but I am unable to handle the 403 errors.

```java
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
          .requestMatchers(endpoints)).authenticated()
          .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}
```

I have been reading the answers, and it seems that creating a custom filter is considered a bad practice. Is it possible to handle 404 and 403 errors with a message? If so, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score -2):

You need ovveride spring security with **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** any request matching the **/api/**** pattern should be authenticated using JWT and anything that doesn't match would be allow to be call without JWT because of this **anyRequest().permitAll()** that the simple way

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated() 
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
}
```

Update sorry quick jumping on spring forgot was 3.0
here another way but didn't  test doing this you will have multi filter and define distinct security configurations also depend of version might have some function that is deprecate you might need look documentation
. I left my others answer enjoy thumb dumb since they like validate they point without giving any solution to help.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain apiSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .securityMatchers((matchers) -> matchers
                    .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/**"), antMatcher("/app/**"))
            ).addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    
    return http.build();
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, and I apologize for my poor English and the question with few details. I will edit it. There have been significant changes in Spring Security 6. The reason I wanted to apply JWT only to my created endpoints is to have a custom handling of the 404 error. If creating a custom filter is considered a bad practice, how could I handle 404 errors with a personalized message? Thank you very much for everything.

Comment: Hello @Darkvision, thank you so much for all your help. I truly appreciate it and I'm grateful for taking the time to answer my question. Your solution helped me a lot to guide myself and achieve the expected result. However, now it returns a 403 error instead of an empty 403. I will read the documentation and learn more about the topic. Thank you very much.